# Javascript image arrays and random images

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, onclick

need a bit of help with a random image array. I need to create 5 images that come up at random when the Start button is clicked (1 at a time) and then have 5 buttons. The 5 buttons that stay there correspond to the random images. First button = image[1] (from array) etc.

img0 stays on the screen and is swapped out for the random images from the array.

I can't seen to get the random image to display. It's probably something simple but I'm banging my head against a wall with it.

Any help you guys can give would be great.

HTML

```
<div style="background-color:grey; position: absolute; left:50px; top:150px">
    <img src="img0.jpg" id="osBus" alt="0" />
</div>
```

CODE

```
<input id="b2" type="button" onclick="btn2_onClick()" value="2" style="position:absolute; left:125px; top:375px"
       disabled class="btns" />

<input id="b3" type="button" onclick="btn3_onClick()" value="3" style="position:absolute; left:225px; top:375px"
       disabled class="btns" />

<input id="b4" type="button" onclick="btn4_onClick()" value="4" style="position:absolute; left:325px; top:375px"
       disabled class="btns" />

<input id="b5" type="button" onclick="btn5_onClick()" value="5" style="position:absolute; left:425px; top:375px"
       disabled class="btns" />
<br />
<script language="javascript">

var Imgs = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jog"];
var Num

function btnStart_onClick() {
    Num = 1 + parseInt(Math.random() * 5);
    document.getElementById("Imgs") == Imgs[Num];
}
```

Any help you guys can offer with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the `src` property.

And a few things:

1. Why are you doing `document.getElementById("Imgs")` when there is no element where `id="Imgs"`?
2. Where is `btnStart_onClick` called from?
3. Use `=` for assignment
4. You only need to multiply by 4, as `Math.random()` returns `0 -> 1`

   `function btnStart_onClick() {
       var imgNum = (1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 4)));
       document.getElementById("osBus").src = imgNum + '.jpg';
   }`

Comment: How would I update the source property? Sorry, I know the code is messy, I'm still very new to this. There is a button defined in the HTML above the div:

    <input id="btnStart" type="button" onclick="btnStart_onClick()" value="Start" />

The "Imgs" is supposed to be the image array.

Comment: `getElementById` and other similar functions are retrieving DOM elements, e.g. your `img` element. If you want to trigger this function on a button click you'll need to create a button element and add the function to the `onclick` method.

Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`Imgs` array does not have an element at index `5`. Use

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * Imgs.length)
```

Also no element has `id` `"Imgs"`; do you mean `"osBus"`? You can change the displayed image by setting the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element.

```
var Imgs = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];
var Num = 0;

function btnStart_onClick() {
    Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Imgs.length);
    document.getElementById("osBus").src = Imgs[Num];
}
```

Comment: The osBus is supposed to just be img0,jpg, thats my fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Imgs = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jog"];

var Num;

function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return  Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1) + min);
}

function btnStart_onClick() {
    Num = randomNumber(0, 4);
    document.getElementById("osBus").src = Imgs[Num];
}
```